# Testing carrierwave keeps returning "Image can't be blank"-error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, carrierwave

I've been implementing carrierwave, which works great in the browser. However, my tests keep returning this:

**Error**

```
  1) Item 
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected valid? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/item_spec.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**factories.rb**

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

FactoryGirl.define do

  sequence(:email) { |n| "User#{n}@example.com"}

  factory :user do
    name     "John doe"
    email
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end

  factory :list do
    name "Lorem ipsum"
    user
  end

  factory :item do
    image { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', 'test_images', 'google.png'), 'image/png') }
    title "Shirt"
    link "www.example.com"
    list
  end
end
```

**item_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Item do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let(:list) { FactoryGirl.create(:list) }

  before do
    @item = list.items.build(title: "Lorem ipsum")
    @item.valid?
    puts @item.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
  end

  subject { @item }

  it { should respond_to(:title) }
  it { should respond_to(:list_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:list) }
  it { should respond_to(:image) }
  it { should respond_to(:remote_image_url) }
  its(:list) { should == list }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when list_id not present" do
    before { @item.list_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when image not present" do
    before { @item.image = "" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "with blank title" do
    before { @item.title = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "with title that is too long" do
    before { @item.title = "a" * 141 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :link, :list_id, :title, :image, :remote_image_url
  belongs_to :list
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :list_id, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :image
end
```

I have a image in the spec/support/test_images folder called google.png.

I'm very new to rails, and any help is thus much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel quite stupid. Forgot to attach an image, which obviously caused the validation to fail.

Had to change:

```
 before do
    @item = list.items.build(title: "Lorem ipsum")
    @item.valid?
    puts @item.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
 end
```

To:

```
  before do
    @item = list.items.build(title: "Lorem ipsum")
    @item.image = fixture_file_upload('/test_images/google.png', 'image/png')
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

`it { should be_valid }`

is failing because (as you might expect) the subject is not valid. You need to find out *why* it is invalid. Try something like this:

```
it "should be valid" do
  subject.valid?
  subject.errors.should be_empty
end
```

Now the example will fail, but the error message will be more descriptive.

Another way to approach this is to add [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) to your project. Then add `binding.pry` where you'd like to open a console:

```
it "should be valid" do
  subject.valid?
  binding.pry
  subject.errors.should be_empty
end
```

Now you can inspect your test objects to figure out how the validation failed.

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention to Pry - it's a great tool!